# Reading CSV file from Sharepoint with Pentaho

Tags: sharepoint, pentaho, kettle, pdi

Is it possible to read a CSV file in a Sharepoint shared folder with Pentaho steps?

I have tried to do it with a HTTP call but with no expected output.